# How to create N1QL query with array parameter couchbase sdk 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, parameters, couchbase, sql++

I want to create a parameterized query in which one of the parameters is an array/list. For example:

```
var query = @"
SELECT
         doctype1.user_id
FROM     bucket doctype1
JOIN     bucket doctype2
ON       doctype2.user_id = doctype1.user_id
AND      doctype2.type = ‘doctype2’
AND      doctype2.value.Value IN [$myset]
WHERE    doctype1.type = ‘doctype1’
AND      doctype1.value.Type = $type
ORDER BY doctype1.user_id
LIMIT 2
OFFSET 0";
```

I've tried things like doing:

- $myset = " 'val1', 'val2' "
- $myset = "[ 'val1', 'val2' ]"
- $myset = new List() { "val1", "val2" }
- $myset = new[] { "val1", "val2"}
- $myset = "[ 'val1', 'val2' ]"

None of which are working

Answer (score 2):

I feel a bit dense but this was the solution for anyone else running into this issue:

I changed my initial string query and removed the square brackets to look like this:

```
AND doctype2.value.Value IN $myset
```

Then I was able to use either

- $myset = new List() { "val1", "val2" }
- $myset = new[] { "val1", "val2" }

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: You should not feel dense! There are bound to be others run into this; thank you for sharing!